# Hi i want to transfer the output of a javascript for loop on a an array from vertical to horizontal

Tags: javascript

As well as how to use java script to manipulate numbers from whole numbers to float and vice versa.
Thank you very much

Comment: Hmmmm.... Interesting issue. Where's your code though?

Comment: We'll need your code to help fix your problems. What have you attempted?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow,.  Please visit this page first,. -> https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

```js
var myArray = ["I", "need", "your", "code", "to", "help", "you"];
myArray.forEach(function(element) {
  console.log(element);
});

console.log(myArray.join(" "));
```

If I have understood correctly your question.

Comment: Yes Mattia,  thank you very much.